# Python ElementTree: Error Trying to implement a pretty-print

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have some python xml code using ElementTree that writes a very ugly xml file.  I wanted to make the xml file a bit more readable.  But ElementTree has no pretty-print function.   In the documentation ElementTree shows an 'indent' method.   When I try to use this indent method, I get the following error.

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/cygdrive/c/data/path/myFile.py", line 756, in <module>
          main()
          ...
          self.writeXML()
          File "/cygdrive/c/data/path/myFile.py", line 248, in writeXML
                self.indent(root)
     File "/cygdrive/c/data/path/myFile.py", line 252, in indent

        i = "\n" + level*"  "
        TypeError: object cannot be interpreted as an index


 def writeXML(self):
   root = self.myTree.getroot()
   self.indent(root)
   self.myTree.write(self.myXML)

 def indent(elem, level=0):
     i = "\n" + level*"  "   #Error Here!!
     if len(elem):
         if not elem.text or not elem.text.strip():
             elem.text = i + "  "
         if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
             elem.tail = i
         for elem in elem:
             indent(elem, level+1)
         if not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip():
             elem.tail = i
     else:
         if level and (not elem.tail or not elem.tail.strip()):
             elem.tail = i
```

Am I using indent incorrectly?  Or is there an error in this code?   Any recommendations for an easier pretty-print?

History:  I used to use PyXML which had a pretty-print. But, PyXML is died when I went to python 2.6.  lxml has a pretty-print but will not install on my system.  So I converted all my code to use ElementTree because I know it works and has most of the basic functionality I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

```
i = "\n" + level*"  "
TypeError: object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

but there is nothing in that statement that looks even vaguely like an index operation. Suggestion: without changing your code in any other way, insert

`print repr(elem), repr(level)`

before the above statement and edit your question to show the result. Also add what version of Python, and show how you imported ElementTree (or cElementTree).

You appear to have copy/pasted a routine from [the effbot's ElementLib](http://effbot.org/zone/element-lib.htm) ... It looks OK apart from the obfuscatory but not fatal `for elem in elem`.

One major problem is that for some strange reason you have made it a method of your class instead of a stand-alone function. Either (1) drag it out of your class and call it like

`indent(root)`

or (2) change its definition to

`def indent(self, elem, level=0)`

and see if the problem goes away.

**Update** The problem will go away:

```
[Python 2.6.6]
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
>>> et.Element('atag') * "   "
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

The above mysterious error message must have been a bug; Python 2.7.1 produces the much more sensible

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'Element'
```

from the same code.

Comment: The first argument needed to be 'self' that did the trick.   So obvious yet so different than the error message.  Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Because you have put this inside a class

```
    def indent(elem, level=0):
        i = "\n" + level*"  "   #Error Here!!
```

I would expect that `elem` is the instance (remember usually we put self here)
and level is actually the `elem` you are trying to pass in

This means that trying to multiply an element by a string is throwing the `TypeError` which I think is plausible.

As John Machin says, pull this code out of the class and leave it as a standalone function and you should have more luck

Comment: Throwing **a** `TypeError` is very plausible; **that** `Typerror` is very implausible. See my updated answer for a much more plausible error message.